# Redirect Wordpress Website to another domain without

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

So I have a wordpress site that I'd like to 301 redirect to a different domain, BUT the original domain permalink has the date in the URL, /yyyy/mm/dd/postname

> domain.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

And I just want it to have the /%postname%/ like

> domain2.com/%postname%/

I tried changing the permalink and using the Redirection plugin to setup a regex, but that didn't work. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also Redirect through code by using Wordpress Function,
Please Add Post_id of `'domain.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/'` and in URL you can add redirect URL wherever you want to redirect

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {
    $post_id = url_to_postid( 'domain.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/' ); 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( $post_id ) ) 
    {
        wp_redirect( 'domain2.com/%postname%/' );
        die;
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_logged_in_redirect' );
```

I hope this will helps you!

Comment: Thanks! But, where do I add that code? And will it do it for my whole website?

Comment: You just mention for  redirecting from one page to other page..Can you more explain me about whole website ?

Comment: I had a website on one domain and I want to redirect it to another domain, where the postname is the same, minus the %year%/%monthnum%/%day%

Comment: @PhilK Check my updated answer..Now You just have to change postname of one domain1 in $post_id and in wp_redirect you just have to put the link where you want to redirect